# Unable to get the exact value of data while working with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typeof

I have a get request where I get data from the server and this is how it looks

```
 getStreakConfigurations(){
    this.loyaltyPointsService.getStreakConfigurations().subscribe( data => {
      this.streakConfiguration = data
 console.log(this.streakConfiguration,'check')
    }
       )
  }
```

when I `console.log` I get

```
{id: 8, tenantId: null, days: 2, points: 3, tier: 'MID'}
```

but when I check the typeof `streakConfid.id` it says `undefined`

```
console.log(typeof this.streakConfiguration.id);
```

why is it `undefined` and why is it not a number ?

Comment: Where do you place the `console.log(typeof this.streakConfiguration.id);`? Within the `subscribe` function?

Comment: not a possible behavior from JS, can you share the exact code snippet from your project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a service that returns this array of objects (`mockDataArr`) and single object(`mockDataObj`):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoyaltyPointsService {
  constructor() {}

  mockDataArr = [
    { id: 1, tenantId: null, days: 2, points: 3, tier: 'MID' },
    { id: 2, tenantId: null, days: 3, points: 5, tier: 'HIGH' },
  ];

  mockDataObj = { id: 2, tenantId: null, days: 3, points: 5, tier: 'HIGH' };

  getStreakConfigurationsArr(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.mockDataArr);
  }

  getStreakConfigurationsObj(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.mockDataObj);
  }
}
```

And then you are using it on controller like below:

```
  public streakConfigurationArr: any;
  public streakConfigurationObj: any;

  constructor(private loyaltyPointsService: LoyaltyPointsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfigurationsArr();
    this.getConfigurationsObj();
  }

  getConfigurationsArr() {
    this.loyaltyPointsService.getStreakConfigurationsArr().subscribe((data) => {
      this.streakConfigurationArr = data;
      console.log(this.streakConfigurationArr);
      console.log(
        'in array of objects id is undefined',
        typeof this.streakConfigurationArr.id
      );
    });
  }

  getConfigurationsObj() {
    this.loyaltyPointsService.getStreakConfigurationsObj().subscribe((data) => {
      this.streakConfigurationObj = data;
      console.log(this.streakConfigurationObj);
      console.log('in object id is number', typeof this.streakConfigurationObj.id);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-iyjcqx?file=src%2Floyalty-points.service.ts)